# JSON is not parsing in c++ builder 2010

Tags: json, c++builder

I'm starting to work with JSON in builder by including `#include<DBXJSON.hpp>`

doing simple parsings but no result

here is my code

```
void __fastcall TForm1::okClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TJSONObject *obj=new TJSONObject();
    TBytes StringBytes = TEncoding::UTF8->GetBytes(Memo1->Text);
    obj->Parse(StringBytes, 0);
    Memo2->Text = obj->ToString();
    obj->~TJSONObject();
}
```

my Memo1->Text contains

```
{
   "firstName": "Иван",
   "lastName": "Иванов",
   "address": {
       "streetAddress": "Московское ш., 101, кв.101",
       "city": "Ленинград",
       "postalCode": 101101
   },
   "phoneNumbers": [
       "812 123-1234",
       "916 123-4567"
   ]

}
```

in the end my Memo2->Text

gets `{}`

Comment: `obj->~TJSONObject();` is very weird code!  Why don't you call `delete obj;`?

Comment: @David M: `obj->~TJSONObject();` is reasonable with (and only with) placement new. `delete obj;` destroys the object *and* attempts to free the memory. Placement new separates memory allocation from object creation, so with it you routinely destroy an object and free the memory separately. There are times it's justified -- but you're right that in this case, it doesn't seem to be. In fact, it appears that the object should just be allocated automatically, as in `TJSONObject obj;` and destroyed automatically as well.

Comment: i changed to `delete obj` but the result is the same not successfull!

Comment: Have you checked the return value of Parse? From the documentation: `If any parse error is encountered, Parse returns a negative number.`

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, this was not supported in C++Builder 2010 because DBXJSON uses Delphi's RTTI which was not correctly supported until C++Builder XE.

Answer (score 1):

For C++Builder there is also JSonCBuilderBlog Library, it is free and open source.

Your source code can be translated in the following way:

```
TMetaObject obj;
obj.Decode(Memo1->Text);
Memo2->Text = obj.Encode();
```

As you can see the above code is very simple and it does not require any delete operator.

Considering your JSON source string, you can access to your data, after decoding it, in the following way:

```
UnicodeString FirstName = obj["firstName"];
UnicodeString LastName  = obj["lastName"];
UnicodeString Street    = obj["address"]["streetAddress"];
UnicodeString City      = obj["address"]["city"];
....
```

Moreover, the JSonCBuilderBlog Library is able to define new data type and makes a strong type checking on JSON source string. This is usefull to validate the data coherence based on the new data type defined by user.

For your reference following the library link: [JSonCBuilderBlog](http://www.cbuilderblog.com/jsoncbuilderblog-class-library/) Class Library.

Comment: Is this library gonna be updated for XE5 and later since it is not working in newer versions of C++ Builder?

Comment: Hi @tracer, Thank you for your info. I'm JSonCBuilderBlog (JSonCBB)library developer and I need your feedback. I have up to date just now the C++XE6, so I released a new version of my library 0.2. It fixes any compiler error. Please, post any your comment also on my site. I quoted you in my update. Thanks!

Comment: I found some problems on C++XE6 64bit compiler. So for now JSonCBB works only on C++XE-XE6 32bit version. I try to solve problem and  post a new version.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try as soon as you give the word (64 bit support would be nice). I tried to access your forum, but it's not working.

Comment: I released the new version 0.3, it supports 32bit and 64bit (CLang). Thanks!